# Inserting Javascript (or text) inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I need to trigger some javascript to load up an extra part of a form in activeadmin.  For the "create" action I've successfully triggered the javascript from the onchange event of a dropdown box, but for the edit action it needs to be triggered from the form load.

I've found I can trigger it with something similar to

```
javascript_tag "loadRecipeEdit(3)"
```

but I can't embed this into the form action for activeadmin without it breaking the structure of the form (formtastic issue)

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :name
        f.input :production_date
        if f.object.new_record?
            f.input :recipe, :input_html => { :onchange => "loadRecipe()" } 
        else
           javascript_tag "loadRecipeEdit(3)" 
        end
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Any thoughts of other ways to trigger the javascript would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found an alternative:

```
f.form_buffers.last << javascript_tag("loadRecipeEdit(3)")
```

Hope its useful!